# How to handle sitemap with large amount of dynamic urls

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap

We are currently building sitemap for our website, and it is clear for me that we need to create a sitemap with ALL urls for each entity we wish to be indexed by google.
It seems completely reasonable and fine to add urls such as

- `example.com/dish-name`
- `example.com/restaurant-name`
- `example.com/region-name`

But how about URLs for combining that entities, such as where to eat dish X in region Y, such as

- `example.com/bolognese/italy`
- `example.com/bolognese/rome`
- `example.com/steak/paris`

etc.

Should i calculate all possible combinations in our system and also add it to XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only add urls to your sitemap if they actually exist and you have the page on your site with those urls.

Comment: those urls exist, but i was wondering is that good approach, to add large amounts of URLs with all possible combinations.

Comment: Yes, if it's on your site and you want it indexed, it should be on the sitemap. The number of items isn't an issue unless it's a very large amount.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good idea to add multi URL for one page. You must avoid this for better SEO.

If the target pages are diff so add all URLs to your sitemap, otherwise find the true strategy and follow that. Just like permalinks in wordpress.